# How to compute actuator torque requirement for Variable pitch mechanism??

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems, propeller, aircraft-physics, variable-pitch

Suggest me any reference to compute the torque requirement for actuator/motor to control the pitch angle of propeller (Variable Pitch Propeller).

Thanks in advance

Arun Ravindran

Comment: Welcome to the site @ArunRavindran. This sounds like a homework question, and it's a bit vague to be honest. what have you looked at already?

Comment: Most variable pitch propellers are controlled by a combination oil pressure, counterweights and springs.  I am not aware of any that use an actuator or motor to control pitch.  If you do a Google search you will find lots of graphics and tutorials explaining how they work.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. We are currently working on design of large UAV class platform. I have came across few techniques where people have used servo/motor to control the pitch angle (beta) variation during their flight to attain optimum efficiency throughout the flight envelop. Please verify Summary of Propeller design procedure and data Vol III - they have given brief explanation about actuator based variable pitch mechanism. Even they have given the calculation for centrifugal twisting moment (torque required to change the beta angle).

Comment: Problem is they have used a constant value without any reference. Kindly suggest me any reference or method to compute the torque required to change the beta angle of blade. Thank you once again.